# Issues trying to create a windows workflow service programmatically using 4.5 that contains CSharpValue expressions

Tags: workflow-foundation

I have successfully created a windows workflow service programmatically using Windows Workflow 4.0.  Windows Workflow 4.0 did not support CSharp expressions, so I needed to use VisualBasic expressions.  Now that we have upgraded to 4.5, I'd like to convert those to VisualBasic expressions to CSharp expressions.  Unfortunately, I am having some errors when I try to use the workflow.

In 4.0, in order for the workflow to be generated and serialized properly, I needed to inform it about which namespaces to use.  For example, I had something like the following:

```
    private static void AddVbNamespaceSettings(WorkflowService service, params Type[] types)
    {
        var vbsettings = VisualBasic.GetSettings(rootObject) ?? new VisualBasicSettings();

        foreach (Type t in types)
        {
            vbsettings.ImportReferences.Add(
                new VisualBasicImportReference
                {
                    Assembly = t.Assembly.GetName().Name, 
                    Import = t.Namespace
                });
        }

        VisualBasic.SetSettings(service, vbsettings);
    }
```

Doing the above, I was able to inform the workflow service which types it needed to evaluate visual basic expressions.

I believe that I need to do something equivalent for CSharp, but I have not been able to discover what that is. Is there something equivalent?

Additionally, I was able to validate the workflow by doing something like:

```
        ValidationResults results = ActivityValidationServices.Validate(service.Body); 
        if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
```

Now that my expressions are in CSharpValues, the validator does not seem to catch bad expressions.  What is the proper way to validate the workflow?

Thanks,
Eric